# Condition statements for a single row data value in a database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms

I am using C# to create a windows form.

I am trying to set a condition statement for a particular value that is retrieved from my database by the onclick of a button. The datatype of the column is 'integer'.

Below is my code:

```
 string checkquantity = "SELECT  `inventory_item`.`Item_Quantity_Available`FROM `inventory_item` , `patient`, `out_treatment`WHERE `inventory_item`.`Item_ID` = `out_treatment`.`Inventory_ID`AND `patient`.`Patient_ID` = `out_treatment`.`Patient_ID`AND `out_treatment`.`Patient_ID`= '" + pid + "' ";
            MySqlCommand selectout = new MySqlCommand(checkquantity, connect);
            MySqlDataAdapter selectdata = new MySqlDataAdapter(checkquantity, connect);
            DataTable selecttable = new DataTable();
            selectdata.Fill(selecttable);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            selectdata.Fill(selecttable);
            selectdata.Fill(ds);
            int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            if ( i <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Out of Stock");
            }
```

I'm new with c#. 
I don't think the `int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;` is the right way.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You have 3 tables in your select, but no joins... You shouldn't be using a DataTable/DataSet if you just want the result of the query, use the `selectout.ExecuteScalar()` command which will return the first column of the first row.

Comment: ok.. i'll try that

Comment: You are concatenating in your PID variable into your select statement.  Read up on "SQL Injection".  That's a _**very**_ bad thing to do.

Comment: `selectout.executescalar()` not working

Comment: I suggest using a more appropriate way to deal with databases like Entity Framework https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ or SqlKata https://sqlkata.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like @Flydog57 said, you should not concatenate your sql query. The best way is to use parameters, for example:

```
string checkquantity = "SELECT  i.Item_Quantity_Available " +
                       "  FROM inventory_item i JOIN out_treatment t ON i.Item_Id = t.Inventory_ID " +
                       "                        JOIN patient p ON t.Patient_ID = p.PatiendID " +           
                       " WHERE t.Patient_ID = @Patiend_ID";
MySqlCommand selectout = new MySqlCommand(checkquantity, connect);
// set the parameter value
selectout.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patiend_ID", patient_id_value);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();          

if (rdr.Read())
{
    if ((int)rdr["Item_Quantity_Available"] == 0)

        MessageBox.Show("Out of Stock");
}
```

In second place, you could use a MySqlDataReader to verify that Item_Quantity_Available is equal to 0, like in the previous example. Otherwise, If you just wants to verify if there is data, the condition could be something like that:

```
if (!rdr.Read())
{
    MessageBox.Show("Out of Stock");
}
```

The third improvemente is to join tables with the join clause.